# Python - combine PostgreSQL query results into a single row

Tags: python, psycopg2

Im using a python code to return a single column's data. But when I print the result, each row will contain `(\t value)`.  But I want to combine everything into a single row in Python(we can do via PSQL, but Im trying to make it work with Python.

#### My Code:

```
import psycopg2

def get_pg_con():
    return psycopg2.connect(dbname='dev', 
      host='POSTGRESIP', 
      user='USER',
      password='PASS',
      port='5432')
      
def handler(handler, context):
    print('test')
    conn = get_pg_con()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    copy_command="""
    select myval from mytbl; """
    cur.execute(copy_command)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    results = ''.join(map(str, result))
    print(results)
```

#### Output

```
(this is,)(\t my new,)(values)
```

#### Expected output

```
this is,
    my new,
values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this approach.

```
for row in result:
        print(''.join(row).encode().decode('utf-8'))
```

It worked, but open for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Each row in in results is a single-element tuple.

Given such a tuple, you can extract the element like this:

```
>>> tuple_ = ('foo',)
>>> val = tuple_[0]
>>> print(val)
foo
```

Or, more elegantly

```
>>> val, = tuple_
>>> print(val)
foo
```

Therefore, given the results of the query, you can do this:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(col for col, in results))
this is,
         my new
values
```